# Setting up smtp server for local use only

Tags: linux, ubuntu, email, postfix, smtp

So I have a security cam that will send out an email notification anytime motion is detected.  I got this to work with gmail and it will properly send out an email.  However, I don't want to use gmail as I would like to write a script that records these messages into a text file which is stored on my network drives so I can view the text report remotely. Therefore I looked into setting up my own smtp server to send out these emails.  I have successfully setup postfix to send local emails.

```
echo "Subject: hello2" | sendmail secadmin@localhost
```

I can then see these emails in `/var/mail` I could then use this file to write the required script.

This is then where I hit a major roadblock.  I have no idea how get the smtp server to send out emails from a remote machine. The camera email setup is as such:

[image]

How do I find out what to put into these settings? If I was to use gmail this is pretty straight forward however I don't even know where to begin when using postfix.  Any help is greatly appreciated.

My only guesses would be:

**SMTP server**: local address of posfix server (192.168.30.7)

**SMTP port**: Could I use port 25 if I dont enable SSL/TLS?

**Sender Address**: secadmin@localhost

**passsword**: Password for my linux server?

**recipient address**: secadmin@localhost

Answer (score 1):

Solved it.  Most of my settings were correct, I just had to make sure my postfix server was actually listening on the right address. FAIL